# Binding drop down list from Enum in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm having Enum class and i have to bind the drop down list in asp.net MVC4(using Razor view engine). I can bind the drop down list and can display in view. But i couldn't show the selected item at edit mode. Please any one help me. I'm havin following code

my ViewModelclass

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
 public string AccountId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="First Name")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Middle Name")]
        public String MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Last Name")]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and Enum class is,

```
 public enum UserType // Office User Types
    {
        Officer = 1,
        Administrator = 2,
        Recruiter = 3
    }
```

and i'm using following code in my controller,

```
Dictionary<string, string> rolename = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserType))
   .Cast<UserType>()
   .Select(v => v.ToString())
   .ToDictionary<string, string>(v => v.ToString());
            ViewBag.Roles = rolename;
   return View();
```

and my view is,

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRoles,new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "Key", "Value",Model.UserRoles.ToString()), new { id = "UserRoles" })
```

Please help me what is my mistake and how to display selected value in dropdown list at edit mode.

Comment: Could it be that `UserRoles` in your model is "Officer", "Administrator", etc. and the key for the drop down is 1, 2, 3, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The following code generates a `SelectList` from and `enum`

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList(System.Type type)
    {
        var output = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (int item in Enum.GetValues(type))
        {
            var si = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem();
            si.Value = item.ToString();

            DisplayAttribute attr =(DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)
                type.GetMember(Enum.GetName(type, item))
                .First().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            si.Text = (attr == null) ? Enum.GetName(type, item) : attr.Name;
            output.Add(si);
        }
        return output;

    }
```

As you can see from the code it also uses Data Annotations `DisplayAttribute` to help in case the name in the `enum` name is not "user friendly".

This can also be abstracted as an extension to `HtmlHelper` though not nessessary.

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList(
        this HtmlHelper helper, 
        System.Type type)
    {
        return EnumToSelectList(type);
    }
```

Usage is simple:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRoles, 
    Html.EnumToSelectList(typeof(UserType))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an enum helper that will give you the select list you need from an enum.  It will also automatically handle your selected value should you have one.  Take a look.

http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23

If you implement the following it may fix your issue:

```
//In the controller
ViewBag.DropDownList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor(myEnumValue);

//In the view
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownList") 

/// OR
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DropDownList, ViewBag.DropDownList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

The above takes advantage of this helper

```
public static class EnumHelper  
{  
    //Creates a SelectList for a nullable enum value  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T? selected)  
        where T : struct  
    {  
        return selected == null ? SelectListFor<T>()  
                                : SelectListFor(selected.Value);  
    }  

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum type  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>() where T : struct  
    {  
        Type t = typeof (T);  
        if (t.IsEnum)  
        {  
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<enum>()  
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });  

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum value  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct   
    {  
        Type t = typeof(T);  
        if (t.IsEnum)  
        {  
            var values = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Enum>()  
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });  

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Convert.ToInt32(selected));  
        }  
        return null;  
    }   

    // Get the value of the description attribute if the   
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value.  
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)  
    {  
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());  

        if (fi != null)  
        {  
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =  
             (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(  
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),  
    false);  

            if (attributes.Length > 0)  
            {  
                 return attributes[0].Description;  
            }  
        }  

        return value.ToString();  
    }  
}
```